# -[NSString intValue] returning completely different value than the string says

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a numeric string and have observed a discrepency where its `intValue` is vastly different from its string value. The code below:

```
NSString *string = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"ID %@",string);
NSLog(@"ID as integer %i",[string intValue]);
```

gives an output:

```
"ID 100004378121454"
"ID as integer 2147483647"
```

The only logical guess I can make is that the string is too long to be converted to an `int`... In any case I tried `longLongValue` and such - to different results but not the one it should be.

Comment: You're right that you're reaching the limits of the 32-bit int there, but the longlongValue should work. What's the outcome then?

Comment: try using unsigned int ( u_int32 max value 9,223,372,036,854,775,808)

Comment: Do you know the 'string' is in fact a NSString and no a NSNumber? You might want to query the class.

Comment: @elio.d That would be the maximum value of a signed 64-bit integer. The maximum value of an unsigned 32-bit integer is approximately 4 billion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your number(100004378121454) is greater number than a simple int can handle, you have to use `long long` type in this case(to not get your number truncated to the int32 maximum value) :

```
NSString *string = @"100004378121454";
NSLog(@"ID %@",string);
NSLog(@"ID as long long %lli",[string longLongValue]);
```

Output :

```
ID              100004378121454
ID as long long 100004378121454
```

Comment: Thanks to all the comments and this answer, i was just baffled as to what initials i was supposed to put after the % to get it to output a long long properly...cheers